# Query for COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if I should be using Sub-selects or not. 
Here is some sample data:

```
Eg. Report Table with Data
-----------------------------
id  BusID   Date        Link  Det   Click
1   32  2011-12-19     0    0     1
2   34  2011-12-21     0    1     0
3   32  2011-12-22     1    0     0
3   32  2011-12-22     1    0     0
4   33  2011-12-23     1    0     0
5   32  2011-12-23     0    0     1
4   33  2011-12-23     1    0     0
5   32  2012-01-05     0    0     1
3   32  2012-01-06     1    0     0
4   33  2012-01-06     1    0     0
5   32  2012-01-08     0    0     1

business Table with Data
-----------------------------
id  name
32  Acme Inc
33  Orange Computers
34  OHBHL Corp
```

What I am looking for is a query to list like the following:

```
DECEMBER 2011
-------------
Acme Inc.   Linked: 5   Det: 3    Clicked:  3
Orange      Linked: 3   Det: 4    Clicked:  4
```

... and so forth for each month/year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SUM(link)`, `SUM(det)`, `SUM(clicked)` and `GROUP BY` date truncate to month and id, name.